# How to use open CV to remove object from the selected part of an image without distorting the background image?

Tags: python, opencv, blur, masking, inpainting

Everyone I'm trying to implement the openCV to remove objects from images by selecting on it but when I select the part to remove by making a square on it then that part will blur with removing the object but I'm not getting the expected result I want without distorting the background part of an image inPainting will use so also I have provided the code please anyone who know the better solution so provide me.

Here, I have provided to you Input Image, Selected Region Image, Output Image

[Input Image -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWr5r.png)

[Selected Region Image -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDzCa.png)

[Output Image -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P41AY.png)

```
import numpy as np

# Function to handle mouse events
def draw_square(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global drawing, mask, mask_history, mask_index, square_start, square_end

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        square_start = (x, y)
        square_end = (x, y)
        # Clear the redo history when a new action is initiated
        mask_history = mask_history[:mask_index + 1]
        mask_index += 1

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing:
            square_end = (x, y)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        if drawing:
            drawing = False
            x1, y1 = square_start
            x2, y2 = square_end
            # Draw a white rectangle on the mask to mark the area to remove
            cv2.rectangle(mask, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), 255, -1)  # Fill the rectangle
            mask_history.append(mask.copy())

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('chair_beach.jpg')

# Set the zoom ratio (adjust this value as needed)
zoom_ratio = 1.0  # No zoom

# Resize the image according to the zoom ratio
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=zoom_ratio, fy=zoom_ratio)

# Get the image size for window creation
image_height, image_width = img.shape[:2]

# Create a mask for user-drawn areas to remove
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)

# Create a window with a fixed size matching the image size
cv2.namedWindow('Image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('Image', image_width, image_height)

# Set the mouse event callback function
cv2.setMouseCallback('Image', draw_square)

drawing = False
square_start = (-1, -1)
square_end = (-1, -1)
mask_history = []
mask_index = -1

while True:
    # Display the image with the mask
    masked_image = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 2, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)

    # Draw the outline of the square on the image
    x1, y1 = square_start
    x2, y2 = square_end
    if drawing:
        cv2.rectangle(masked_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)  # Red outline

    cv2.imshow('Image', masked_image)

    # Check for key press
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

    # Undo the last action if 'z' is pressed
    if key == ord('z') and mask_index > 0:
        mask_index -= 1
        mask = mask_history[mask_index].copy()

    # Redo the last undone action if 'y' is pressed
    if key == ord('y') and mask_index < len(mask_history) - 1:
        mask_index += 1
        mask = mask_history[mask_index].copy()

    # Reset the mask if 'r' is pressed
    if key == ord('r'):
        mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
        mask_history = []
        mask_index = -1

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm wanted to get an accurate result by removing object from Image using OPenCV without any distortion of an image.

Comment: the oldest two inpainting modes are *not* AI-based.